# How to configure PostgreSQL 9.3 Auto Backup

Tags: database, postgresql, backup

I am trying to setup Database Auto backup for PostgreSQL 9.3 with windows task scheduler, here is the batch code but it is not taking any back, What am I missing?

```
   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
   )
   SET PGPATH=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\
   SET SVPATH=C:\Users\......\Documents\PostgresqlBack\backup\
   set datestr=%month%_%day%_%year%
   echo datestr is %datestr%

   set BACKUP_FILE=<NameOfTheFile>_%datestr%.backup
   echo backup file name is %BACKUP_FILE%
   SET PGPASSWORD=<test_user>
   echo on
  %PGPATH% -i -h <localhost> -p 5432 -U <test123> -F c -b -v -f    %SVPATH%%BACKUP_FILE% <test>
```

Comment: what problem do you meet?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I can see the task is running but there no backup file in that specified directory path